# Does JDBC drivers talk directly to database?

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I have some doubts regarding JDBC API's, JDBC drivers and the actual database.

I understand that We need JDBC drivers in conjunction with JDBC API's in order to talk to a database.

I have the following doubts:

1) Are JDBC API's fully implemented i.e. has Sun/Oracle themselves implemented JDBC API's?

2) We need jdbc drivers, and these jars need to be in the application classpath which is  trying to connect db. Now, who does provide these JDBC drivers?

3) Are JDBC driver's  the implementation of JDBC API's? What is the difference between JDBC driver and JDBC API.

4) When we write an application which interacts with DB (using JDBC), the jdbc drivers are on the client side, do jdbc drivers directly talk to the database? or is there any 'software' in database to which these drivers interact with? In which language are these drivers written?

5) How does jdbc drivers communicate with database server? (Assuming java application running in one server and database in another server). Is it TCP/IP , socket programming internally?

Thanks

Comment: Please ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: They are all related to the same concept, else i would have written them in different questions. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/intro.html#1018464

Comment: for developer who want more info; download [MySQL JDBC driver, where is the source?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11017642/992406) and search for files `MysqlIO.java`,`ConnectionImpl.java` and `StatementImpl.java` and take a look at their source code;

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind response. Best Regards,Vipin

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Are JDBC API's fully implemented i.e. has Sun/Oracle themselves
>   implemented JDBC API's?

No, there has to be a separate implementation for each database.

> 2) We need jdbc drivers, and these jars need to be in the application classpath which is trying to connect db. Now, who does provide these JDBC drivers?

Usually the database vendor but if the database has an open architecture, there could be alternate implementations created by others.

> 3) Are JDBC driver's the implementation of JDBC API's? What is the difference between JDBC driver and JDBC API.

Exactly what you described. The API defines a contract clients can use, the drivers provide the implementation of that contract. What complicates matters somewhat is that the JDBC API has a separate version (I think the latest one is 4.2) and not every driver supports every version of the API. You'll always have to check the documentation of the specific driver.

> 4) When we write an application which interacts with DB (using JDBC), the jdbc drivers are on the client side, do jdbc drivers directly talk to the database? or is there any 'software' in database to which these drivers interact with? In which language are these drivers written?

It depends on the [type of the driver](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-driver-types.htm). Type 4 drivers communicate directly with the database, type 3 drivers communicate with a middleware which acts as intermediary, type 2 depend on native libraries, whereas type 1 use locally installed ODBC drivers. In practice 99% of drivers you'll encounter will be type 2 or 4. If you connect to an Oracle database for example, the two drivers are called OCI and THIN respectively.

> 5) How does jdbc drivers communicate with database server? (Assuming java application running in one server and database in another server). Is it TCP/IP , socket programming internally?

Yes, it's along those lines. But there's nothing in the API that mandates that, it's just the most obvious way of communicating. Some databases will even run embedded in your application, meaning that "communication" will be achieved by simple local method calls.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Are JDBC API's fully implemented i.e. has Sun/Oracle themselves implemented JDBC API's?

I don't accept your definition. 'Fully implemented ' doesn't mean anything in particular, and certainly not that Oracle has to do it. JDBC drivers are provided by the database vendor.

> 2) We need jdbc drivers, and these jars need to be in the application classpath which is trying to connect db.

Err, yes.

> Now, who does provide these JDBC drivers?

This is just the same question as (1), and it has the same answer.

> 3) Are JDBC driver's the implementation of JDBC API's?

Yes.

> What is the difference between JDBC driver and JDBC API.

What you just said.

> 4) When we write an application which interacts with DB (using JDBC), the jdbc drivers are on the client side, do jdbc drivers directly talk to the database?

Usually but not always. There are four levels defined. It's entirely up to he implementors.

> or is there any 'software' in database to which these drivers interact with?

Again it depends.

> In which language are these drivers written?

JDBC drivers are written in Java, with possibly a native component. It depends.

> 5) How does jdbc drivers communicate with database server? (Assuming java application running in one server and database in another server). Is it TCP/IP , socket programming internally?

Usually, but again it depends. In the case of a local MySQL server for example it can be a Unix-domain socket: in the case of an embedded database there may be no communication at all, just method calls.